# Allow certain special characters - Regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to allow only spaces, hyphens, underscores & commas along with alphabets & numbers. But this is not working as desired.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtQuestion"
Display="dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9-_,\s]$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Character   ShownResult
-            valid
_            valid
,            valid
-_           invalid //this should be valid for me
```

Comment: Your character group `[a-zA-Z0-9-_,\s]` matches a single character. Add a quantifier like `[a-zA-Z0-9-_,\s]+` to make it match multiple characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put  `-` symbol at the last or at the first inside the character class or consider escaping it otherwise it would act as a range operator.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_,\s-]+$
```

Add `+` after the character class to allow one or more characters otherwise it would allow only a single character from the list.

Comment: Did not work. Any of the sp.chars repeated is showing invalid eg.-_ or -,or __

Comment: add `+` after the char class to allow one or more chars otherwise it would allow only a single character from the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_,\s]*$
```

Escape `-` so that it does not define a range.Also use `*`or `+` to include one or more characters.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/21

Answer (score 0):

If you want text field to except only Numbers and Char @%?* use following RE

ValidationExpression="[0-9@%?*]*"

This will work for any combination of characters